# Calculating the CRC manually using CCITT polynomial i.e 0x1021

Tags: crc

Iam working on a real time data acquisition. In that I should send a string of ASCII characters in order to initiate the communication between the device and the laptop. This is the scenario.
Coming to the point, I want to know how to manually calculate the CRC for the following sequence 16,2,71,16,3,using CCITT polynomial i.e 0x1021.

I used online calculator for calculating the CRC using the following link.
http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

And now since that I know the values obtained in the online calculations and I am planning to manually verify them.Please help me with the issue if anyone is aware of the method used to calculate CRC.
Any help is appreciated.
Tnaks in advance.

Comment: You need to find and provide more information on the CRC. There is more than one CRC attributed (some incorrectly) to CCITT. The online calculator you found may not even be calculating the CRC you actually need. What documentation do you have that says what kind of CRC you need? Does that documentation provide an example of a calculated CRC for verification? Does it tell you in what order to send the two CRC bytes? Can you provide a link?

Comment: The syntax which I am following is according to the one which I found in the documentation. And the documentation doesn't provide any example as such. The order which I need to follow is as follows; first the higher byte will be sent and immediately followed by lower byte, i.e after the five characters which I mentioned earlier will be followed by these two CRC values.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation? If not, can you provide, _exactly verbatim_, what the documentation says about the CRC?